# Not able to understand ` recursion and closure scope` on this flattening object

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I should suppose to flatten a object, to do this I use this function:

```
var flatter = function(ob){
    var f = {};
    for(var i in ob) {
        if(typeof ob[i] == 'object') {
            var newOb = flatter(ob[i]);
            for(var x in newOb) {
                f[i+'.'+x] = newOb[x];
            }
        }else{
            f[i] = ob[i];
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

works fine. I am getting proper result to applying this object:

```
var ob = {
    "address" : {
        "details" : {
            "first" : "siva",
            "last" : "sankara",
            "mam":["mam1","mam2"]
        }
    }
};
```

the result is :

```
reslut : Object {address.details.first: "siva", address.details.last: "sankara", address.details.mam.0: "mam1", address.details.mam.1: "mam2"}
```

But I am not able to understand the result how i am getting. I understand that, this is oriented with `recursion` and `closure scope` - But seaching google I am not get any clear tutorial or article.

Any one help me to understand this my step by step please?

[Here is the live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S9wV4/)

Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function flatter(ob){
    'use strict';
    var f = {}, //return this
        key;
    for(key in ob) { //for each key
        if (ob.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if(typeof ob[key] === 'object') {   //if value is object
                //flatten this object again. Assign result to newOb
                var newOb = flatter(ob[key]);   
                for(var x in newOb) {
                    f[key + '.' + x] = newOb[x];
                }
            } else {
                f[key] = ob[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

you can translate this code in something like that

```
function flatter(ob){
    'use strict';
    var f = {}, //return this object
        key;
    for(key in ob) { //for each key
        if (ob.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if(typeof ob[key] === 'object') {   //if value is object
                var newOb = (function (ob) {
                    'use strict';
                    var f = {}, //return this object
                        key;
                    for(key in ob) { //for each key
                        if (ob.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            if(typeof ob[key] === 'object') {   //if value is object
                                var newOb = flatter(ob[key]);
                                for(var x in newOb) {
                                    f[key + '.' + x] = newOb[x];
                                }
                            } else {
                                f[key] = ob[key];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return f;
                }(ob[key]));
                for(var x in newOb) {
                    f[key + '.' + x] = newOb[x];
                }
            } else {
                f[key] = ob[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

main idea is that every function call can be substituted by body of this function.
Object itself is a recursive structure, because can content objects. If given

```
{
    id: 12345,
    name: 'John',
    friends: [12346, 75645, 96768]
}
```

recursion is not needed. Object doesn't contain any objects, so it could be straigtened without additional function call (by the way it is flat). If given

```
{
    id: 12345,
    name: {
        first: 'John',
        last: 'Doe'
    },
    friends: [12346, 75645, 96768]
}
```

then object contains object as field. So you can use function flatter where function call is substituted with body of function. If given

```
{
    id: 12345,
    name: {
        first: 'Helen',
        last: {
            beforeMarriage: 'Dobsky',
            afterMarriage: 'Bobsky'
        }
    },
    friends: [12346, 75645, 96768]
}
```

then one can't do without 3 function calls. So you can copy body of function three times. But, object can have [infinitely] very deep structure. So number of nested bodies of function is unknown. So, instead of nesting body of function into function recursive call is used.
Recursive function should have at least one exit point to avoid infinite recursion

```
return f;
```

in our case. This exit point can be reached because number of fields in object is finite. This is not the only way to solve task. As object looks like tree (a kind of) recursion could be substituted with stack, which keeps complex fields and after processing simple fields return back to stack of objects and treat them in a loop.


Stack implementation. Not beautiful, but works)

```
function iflatter(input) {
    'use strict';
    var f = {}, //return this object
        key,
        stack = [],
        ob,
        prefix,
        name;
    stack.push(["", input]);
    while (stack.length != 0) {
        [prefix, ob] = stack.pop();
        for(key in ob) { //for each key
            if (ob.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (prefix !== "") {
                    name = prefix + "." + key;
                } else {
                    name = key;
                }
                if(typeof ob[key] === 'object') {
                    stack.push([name, ob[key]]);
                } else {
                    f[name] = ob[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an Object to `flatter()`. When the Object has a property that has a value that is an Object itself, it passes that Object to `flatter()` again, or recursively. See `if(typeof ob[i] == 'object')`? That means that if `ob` has property `i` and its value (gotten as `ob[i]`) is an Object. Note `var flatter = function(){}` is equivalent to `function flatter(){}`.